# PHP get value from input radio

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a form that has input(radio) and the name of the input is (`question_<?php echo $question['id'];`). Now the form redirects me to the different page where i need to use this input. How do i use $_POST on the page? (I am a little confused because of echo in the name...)

My code:

```
<form action="SaveData.php" method="post" id="SubmitForm">
  <input type="radio" name="question_<?php echo $question['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $answer['id']; ?>">
</form>
```

EDIT:
I have 3 same inputs as this one above (I have a while loop for sql query)
I need to get value of selected input so i can later store it in database as user answer to the question

```
 <?php
 $stm3 = $con->prepare("select * from answer where question_id = :question_id");
 $stm3->bindValue("question_id",$question['id']);
 $stm3->execute();
 ?>
 <?php while ($answer = $stm3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
   <li id="odgovor">
     <input type="radio" name="question_<?php echo $question['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $answer['id']; ?>">
     <span><?php echo $answer['content']; ?></span>
   </li>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: `$_POST['question_questionIdHere']`? It's probably better to have the name as `question[<?= $question['id'] ?>]` and retrieve as `$_POST['question'][$id]` tho (as an array).

Comment: I have 5-40 questions (user picks) each question has 2-3 inputs @shihab